# c - system function print Access is denied

Tags: c, directory, system

I tried to print directory by using the cmd command "dir" but system function print Access is denied even when i run the program as adminstrator.

```
    char line[256];
char directory[256];
char temp[512]="dir ";
int type;
FILE* file;
puts("enter directory");

gets(directory);


strcat(temp,directory);
strcat(temp," >> d:\temp.txt");
system(temp);


file=fopen("d:\temp.txt","r");
```

Answer (score 1):

`d:\temp.txt` change to `d:\\temp.txt`

also `"d:\temp.txt"` to `"d:\\temp.txt"`

`\` is escape sequence in string literal.